# MetaMask not showing the testrpc accounts

Tags: testrpc, metamask

I run testrpc on the terminal and I get the 9 accounts but when I go on crhome and check on metamask after selecting the testrpc blockchain it won't show any of the 9 accounts from metamask but instead 2 random generated wallets...what can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it working! had to run testrpc with `testrpc -m <12 word metamask password that gives when downloading metamask>`

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Please come back after 48 hours and accept your own answer :-)

Comment: Did you pass the words between quotation? I couldn't make it work either way (with and without). I keep getting eth_getBlockByNumber in testrpc.

Comment: This eth_getBlockByNumber does not seem to be wrong. I put the words in quotation marks. Afterwards I could import the additional accounts in MetaMask using the private keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

- Run `testrpc` in your command line and then copy the output mnemonic
  displayed below the account addresses and private keys.
- Use the copied mnemonic as the seed phrase while logging in the
  metamask and you will be provided with accounts[0] of testrpc as
  default account.
- You can also add other 9 accounts by importing them using their
  private keys.