# Can I use multiple Ethereum mnemonics in Metamask

Tags: testrpc, metamask, coinbase

When I first installed Metamask and each time I start testrpc, I get a new mnemonic section of words to use for that testrpc.

I've already configured my MetaMask with four accounts from a prior run of testrpc, with that coinbase having ether that I mined on the testrpc.

So I wonder, if I put in a new set of mnemonic words from the new testrpc run, will I loose the existing accounts in Metamask and invalidate them? Can I go back to them by putting the original mnemonics later?

Or should I have started up testrpc the second time with the mnemonics from when I installed Metamask per this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/metamask-not-showing-the-testrpc-accounts):

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you stop and start testrpc the accounts' balances will be reset to 100eth.

You can run testrpc -m "word1 word2 word3 etc" to restore the wallet with the same accounts/addresses that were generated before, but still the balances will be reset.

Accounts won't be invalidated by changing the mnemonic, you'll just have to lock Metamask and unlock it again using the mnemonic you previously used to access the accounts associated with that mnemonic. (As well as running testrpc with said mnemonic as I explained before).

Comment: Just in case this helps anyone, I stopped and started testrpc without a -m parameter which would have had my old secret words. So restarting testrpc without -m gave me a new set of accounts and a new set of secret words. Then I used the Metamask Import Account to add the private key of one of the new accounts and then I was able to see and accept the transaction from the testrpc in Metamask.