# Petshop tutorial of Truffle doesn't work. Confused with ports 7545, 8545,& 0 eth on metamask

Tags: truffle, testrpc, metamask

I am using testrpc,  metamask and Truffle. I followed Petshop tutorial on Truffle. The Truffle framework had.default. 7545 as local host port in it.. But my system gave 8545 port. The Petshop  app is running, but nothing is proceeding. And metamask is shows 0eth..it should  be 99. I need some help to understand all this

Comment: Is your blockchain server running?

Comment: Yeah it is. On 8545 . And. I got the Petshop on my browser too. But I am not able  to do next sequences.  And metamask shows 0 eth

Comment: Can you add your truffle.js?

Comment: module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};

Comment: module.exports = {
  
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};

Comment: How did you connect your metamsk?

Comment: I installed it in the chrome... As extension.. .

Comment: How should I connect.. It was not mentioned in that Truffle tutorial

Comment: I m using Truffle

Comment: The app has nothing to do with the blockchain server. What blockchain rpc are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your metamask is not connected to local host 8545. From the drop down option in metamask select local host 8545 and you should view test accounts and their respective balances.

Comment: I selected 8545 and I got a account with 0 eth

Comment: I selected 8545 and I got a account with 0 eth... And my Petshop from Trufflle/tutorial don't work

Comment: testrpc accounts will not come by default. After you run testrpc, simply go to Metamask and click Add account. Metamask will add one of the account generated by testrpc command and 100 Ether default. Metamask on its own does not store information to identify which account belongs to which network.

Comment: refer response given in this question 
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/metamask-not-showing-the-testrpc-accounts

Comment: But need sme info about what's happening behind actually..... I could  transact... And the transactions are available in metamask and ganache.....

Comment: Glad to know that, what are your questions, will try to answer.             
Please upvote if my answer helped you!

Comment: Yeah ofcourse.. What should I learn next.. I mean any suggestions for the next step.. And I have a doubt about. The transaction..whom did I send the eth..??

Comment: Now when  I transacting.... All the nodes are turning into... success....

Comment: You can check Udemy.com, they have plenty of courses in Solidity. The ETHERS in your transaction are only for testing purpose and exist till your testrpc is running after that they vanish. In real life applications, there are accounts (like in Metamask) to which Ethers flow across.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the following steps: 
1. Select Custom RPC under Networks in the Metamask
2. Type http://localhost:7545 under New RPC URL, then save.
3. You just added a new private network to select from (http://localhost:7545 )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you run testrpc on separate terminal. Port 8545 corresponds to testrpc